# (VHDL-1154) near 'std_logic_vector' ; type conversion expects one single argument

Tags: binary, vhdl, fpga, division, lattice-diamond

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
use ieee.math_real.all;
Use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

port 
(
    
    signal Led_7                :   out std_logic := '1';
    signal Led_6                :   out std_logic := '1';
    signal Led_5                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Led_4                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Led_3                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Led_2                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Led_1                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Led_0                :   out std_logic := '0';
    signal Binary8bitLED                :   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000"

);

architecture rtl of i2s_interface_1 is

signal Binary8bitData               :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10010110";
signal Binary8bitdivider            :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00001010";

begin
        prescaler: process(clk)     
    begin

    Binary8bitLED   <= std_logic_vector((to_signed(to_integer(to_signed(Binary8bitData)) /                    (to_integer(to_signed(Binary8bitdivider))))),8);



    Led_7 <= '1';
    Led_6 <= '1';
    Led_5 <= '1';
    Led_4 <= '1';
    Led_3 <= '1';
    Led_2 <= '1';
    Led_1 <= '1';
    Led_0 <= '1';
    
    -- Binary8bitLED Output here

    end process;
end architecture;
```

The code is a snippet of the relevant bits. I want to divide
(Binary8bitData / Binary8bitdivider)
to get a remainder of 15 so "00001111"  - > Binary8bitLED

convert the remainder into the LED's on my FPGA.

its a test code to divide binary numbers and I'm looking to show the answer through 8 LED's.

10010110 / 1010 = 15 r 0.

Comment: Adding the missing part of the entity declaration, commenting out the use clauses for Synopsys packages (leaving IEEE std_logic_1164 and numeric_std), commenting out the process sensitivity list and adding an explicit wait statement and `Binary8bitLED <= std_logic_vector (signed(Binary8bitData) / signed(Binary8bitdivider));` analyzes (compiles). Package numeric_std contains signed and unsigned division "/" operator overloads unlike the Synopsys packages here with a quotient length of 8. Provide a [mcve], package math_real is not used as shown either.

Comment: The output should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpx0.jpg). The use of signed division is performed based on the original assignment statement. The waveform here shows both signed decimal and hex values. A [mcve] here implies removing the process sensitivity to clk which isn't declared a `wait for 10 ns; wait;` was appended to the process. Some simulators allow the use of top level signals with default values.

Comment: Hello user16145658,
In your simulated example. result of the division writes to the left 4 bits and the right most 4 bits becomes inherited by the Binary8BitDate.
`Binary8bitLED <= std_logic_vector (signed(Binary8bitData) / signed(Binary8bitdivider));`
10010110
----------- = 11110110
00001010
This division is incorrect. it should come out as 00001111. 
Could this mean the above line you sent (thank you) needs the <= changed to => to correct this with a (others "0") appended to it.
`Binary8bitLED => std_logic_vector (signed(Binary8bitData) / signed(Binary8bitdivider)) and (others "0");

Comment: Hello user16145658, 
With the amended line, i have an error to not use "/" operator.

Comment: Hello user16145658, 

I will try and create another work space with just this problem and post the full code here in text later.

Answer (score 2):

`to_signed(Binary8bitData)` cannot find an appropriate function, as slv to `signed` conversion can be done by a simple type conversion rather than a conversion function:

```vhdl
signed(Binary8bitData)
```

But you have a further issue:
You have included the non-standard synopsys `std_logic_arith` package. This has duplicate definitions of `signed` and `unsigned` types defined in the VHDL standard `numeric_std` package. This means the compiler does not know which version of `to_signed` or `signed` type you want, and hence all will be invisible. You should delete the line:

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
```

from your code.

Comment: With the changes above i get the same error. (VHDL-1154) near 'std_logic_vector' ; type conversion expects one single argument. 

`library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
Use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;`

`Binary8bitLED <= std_logic_vector((signed(to_integer(signed(Binary8bitData)) / (to_integer(signed(Binary8bitdivider))))),8);` 

That's the new line added. Still doesn't like converting it.

Comment: `Integer` => `signed` conversion required two paramters - the value to convert and the length of the resulting vector. Your original `to_signed` call does not have the 2nd operand, and your modified code removed the `to_signed` function for the integer -> signed conversion.

Comment: Thanks Tricky for your support.
`Binary8bitLED <= std_logic_vector((to_signed(to_integer(to_signed(Binary8bitData)) mod (to_integer(to_signed(Binary8bitdivider))))));`

Adding to_ back does remove the first error, now it complains about the integer.

`(VHDL-1272) type error near 'binary8bitdata' ; expected type 'integer'`

i expected both signals to sign and then convert to integer for the division process, then back to signed and converted into std_logic_vector.

is it best to separate this line out into smaller parts?
or
should i be asking how you would implement this?

Comment: I don't think you understood my post. You need both `to_signed` conversion function and `signed` type conversion in your expression. `to_signed` requires a 2nd parameter specifying the resulting length also.

Comment: I would also not use the / or mod operators if this is for an FPGA implementation. It can produce large slow logic and some tools (vivado for example) won't compile it unless the divisor is a constant power of 2.

Comment: Hello Tricky, 
I am using an FPGA, if im not going to use / or mod, is there another way to do this? 
Thank you.